# Showing some rows in textboxes on a Form using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a query that returns for example 5 rows, I want to show thes these rows(fields) in textboxes. but it only shows me one record. I have also set Default view Property of my form into Continuous form. her is my code:

```
Private Sub List2_DblClick(Cancel As Integer)
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT XValue, YValue,Wert FROM tb_DCM_Daten WHERE (FzgID=" & Forms!frm_fahrzeug!ID & " AND [Name]='" & List2.Value & "')")
If rst.RecordCount <> 0 Then

Do While Not rst.EOF
  Text8.SetFocus
  Text8.Text = rst.Fields("XValue").Value

  Text10.SetFocus
  Text10.Text = rst.Fields("YValue").Value

  Text11.SetFocus
  Text11.Text = rst.Fields("Wert").Value
  rst.MoveNext
Loop   
  End If
End Sub
```

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands now, your code would loop through the Recordset, put the values from the first record into the textboxes, then overwrite those values with the ones from the second record, and overwrite *those* with the values from the third record, and so on.

It sounds like you want a subform. Have a look at the Office tutorial [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-HA010098674.aspx) for more information.